# Difference between cast to &(void*&)variable vs. (void**)variable

Tags: c++, casting

What is the difference between the two casts below (uncommented casts):

```
#include <iostream>

void Foo(){}

int main()
{
    //reinterpret_cast<void*>(Foo)<<"\n";             //0x4014e0   
    std::cout<<reinterpret_cast<void**>(Foo)<<"\n"; //0x4014e0
    std::cout<<&reinterpret_cast<void*&>(Foo)<<"\n";//0x4014e0
}
```

They both print the exact same value. I cannot figure out a difference. However, it makes a difference in the following snippet:

```
template<typename U>
void DetourFunction(void** OriginalFunction, U HookFunction)
{
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(OriginalFunction, reinterpret_cast<void*>(HookFunction));
    DetourTransactionCommit();
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
}

int main()
{
    DetourFunction(reinterpret_cast<void**>(Foo), MyAddress); //doesn't work & crashes
    DetourFunction(&reinterpret_cast<void*&>(Foo), MyAddress); //works & does not crash
}
```

The reason I'm asking is because I tried to template it like so:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void DetourFunction(T OriginalFunction, U HookFunction)
{
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(&reinterpret_cast<void*&>(OriginalFunction), reinterpret_cast<void*>(HookFunction));
    DetourTransactionCommit();
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
}

int main()
{
    DetourFunction(Foo, MyAddress); //seems to be equivalent to reinterpret_cast<void**>(); Crashes
}
```

So again, what is the difference between the two casts and how can I template my function so that I can do the following?

```
DetourFunction(SomeFunc, SomeOtherFunc);
```

Comment: You can `reinterpret_cast` something to a reference? Didn't know that. I'm guessing it just ignores the reference part.

Comment: @user2357112: Not sure what you mean by "ignores the reference part" -- the reference part actually makes a very big difference in the result.

Comment: Note that you are not in the realm of well-defined behavior, since an object pointer like `void **` is not guaranteed to be able to contain a pointer to a function.

Comment: The function defined in the Microsoft Detours API is: `LONG WINAPI DetourAttach(PVOID *ppPointer, PVOID pDetour);` It requires the `Void**`. I'm aware of what I'm casting to in order to use the API. I'm just not sure why one fails and the other doesn't.

Comment: @Mehrdad: What does a `reinterpret_cast<void *&>` do, then? This is beyond my C++ knowledge. I understand what casting to a void pointer would do, but casting to a *reference* to a void pointer?

Comment: @user2357112: `reinterpret_cast<void *&>(v)` is equivalent to `*reinterpret_cast<void **>(&v)` (if the address-of operator isn't overloaded). Consider what happens if `v` is declared as `unsigned char` on a typical x86 machine: in that case, this expression would be reading 3 bytes of memory *past* the single byte allocated to `v`, which I believe is undefined behavior. That's quite different from `reinterpret_cast<void *>(v)`, which would be reinterpreting the value of `v` as a pointer (which I think is unspecified), and would *not* read anything outside of the variable's allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
&reinterpret_cast<void*&>(OriginalFunction)
```

you're taking the address of a local variable, which is not what you want, because it'll be gone when `DetourFunction` exits.

Comment: YES!! This! Finally. After 3 hours. You're right, I changed it and it works. I had to make the template `T& OriginalFunction`. However, it still doesn't explain why casting to `void**` makes it fail.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: It fails because when you pretend `OriginalFunction` is a `void**` and then try to dereference it, you're interpreting the address of the *function* (which is probably the address of its first *instruction*) as a `void*`, which is not what you want. I think Detours is expecting to get the address of a variable that's pointing to the function, not the address of the function itself casted to `void**`.